# Book/s about apostasy throughout Jewish history

Tags: history, product-recommendation, books-generally, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, heresy

I am looking for book/s  on the subject of apostasy throughout Jewish history. I haven't been able to find anything that focuses on this subject. I would appreciate any pointers

What I have in mind are books that discuss the individuals who are known to have been apostates from the earliest known cases such as Julius Tiberius Alexander, through the tannaitic/amoraic years, e.g. Acher, through the numerous medieval converts to Christianity like Shlomo Halevi, Nicolo Donin, Pablo Christiani, to Johannes Pfefferkorn, up until the 20th century.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=OvZcmLLeAfAC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Jewish-Apostasy-Modern-World-Endelman/dp/0841910294

Comment: here's a more recent one https://books.google.com/books?id=b6QpBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Are you familiar with Rabbi Hamburger book called משיחי שקר?  It's on Hebrew

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of works about Acher, from the [historical-fiction](https://books.google.com/books?id=EvngtuehE4oC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)  to the [scholarly](https://books.google.com/books?id=ksTtuOEoQUgC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)  and [Hebrew](https://books.google.com/books?id=GLHfAAAAMAAJ&q=%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A1%20%D7%97%D7%98%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2&dq=%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A1%20%D7%97%D7%98%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HPhIVbTzCIj9oQTjgoDYCQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA).  In addition to the books I mentioned in the comments above, various books by Robert Chazan discuss the medieval figures you mention. For a book on 20th century converts to (and from) Christianity, see [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0739196081).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new book that is quite well written especially for a former Skver Chossid.  It is his own memoir of his journey to apostasy but you might find it useful.  [All Who Go Do Not Return](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1555977057) by [Shulem Deen](http://www.shulemdeen.com/about.html).